# msg.value always shows 0 in remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, remix

I am a beginner of solidity and rewriting a Casino DApp code based on the following link:

https://itnext.io/create-your-first-ethereum-dapp-with-web3-and-vue-js-c7221af1ed82

Now I am testing solidity code in remix and getting an error in the second `require` function in `bet` function since `msg.value` is 0.

How should I fix this?

This is my current code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier Owned {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
}

contract Mortal is Ownable {
  function kill() public Owned { 
    selfdestruct(owner);
  }
}

contract Casino is Mortal{
  uint minBet;
  uint houseEdge;

  event Won(bool _status, uint _amount);
  event Log(uint _value);

  function Casino(uint _minBet, uint _houseEdge) payable public {
    require(_minBet > 0);
    require(_houseEdge <= 100);
    minBet = _minBet;
    houseEdge = _houseEdge;
  }

  function() public {
    revert();
  }

  function bet(uint _number) payable public {
    require(_number > 0 && _number <= 10);
    require(msg.value >= minBet);

    uint winningNumber = block.number % 10 + 1;

    if (_number == winningNumber) {
      uint amountWon = msg.value * (100 - houseEdge)/10;
      if(!msg.sender.send(amountWon)) revert();
      emit Won(true, amountWon);
    } else {
      emit Won(false, 0);
    }
  }

  function checkContractBalance() Owned public view returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }

}
```

Updates;
I gave 20 eth and values to Casino contract when I deploy it.
[image]

Comment: setting the value of your transaction. From Remix: run -> first box -> value input: write something there and execute you transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Value fields on constructor are putted on Wei (normally) anb go between `""`.
Also the same for strings.**

So on your deploy button it should put: `"100000", "10".`

I also recommend you to use uint256 variables. **It'll reduce your gas costs.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, `msg.value` got 20000000000000000000 wei thanks to your advice!
I am still getting an error in the same line though...

Comment: Heheh, nice! Remember to vote the asnswer or mark it as correct in order to help others to reach it easier!

Comment: For the other error, you can create another question and wait for an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone, like me, was trying to understand how to set some value to msg in Remix for a test, the trick is this:

```
///#value: 100
function testSomething() payable public {
   Assert.greaterThan(msg.value, uint(50), 'value should be > 50');
}
```

If you run this code above it will be OK. Because you need to put "///#value: {desired value}" - With three dashes and a blank space between #value and the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Remix, use the field named **Value** above the deploy button. It is the same field that is used to choose the initial contract balance on deploy when the constructor is payable.

[image]

Then click the button that calls the payable function that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was following advice from other users, filling in the Value field in the IDE, but still getting 0 wei as the `msg.value`

The problem for me was that when I scrolled down to call the function ***I accidentally scrolled down on the text entry field, and changed the value from 1 to 0*** ‍♀️

If you've tried everything, try clicking outside of the text entry box to ensure the value is saved, before calling the function!

[image: screenshot of entry field]